# New Thread not executing the code properly

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a function that is called when a button is pressed and it has a thread that was supposed to send and clear a TextView text, but it is not happening.
Also no stackTrace.

```
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        if (input_text.getText().length() > 0) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextMessage message = new TextMessage(input_text.getText().toString(), 0, MainHandler.getUserID(), MainHandler.getUsername());
                    MainHandler.sendObject(message);
                    input_text.setText("");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Edit:
Forgot to start the thread, spent hours at the time looking for the problem when it was so obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't starting your thread:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextMessage message = new TextMessage(input_text.getText().toString(), 0, MainHandler.getUserID(), MainHandler.getUsername());
                MainHandler.sendObject(message);
                input_text.setText("");
            }
        }).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly call `start()` (not `run()`) on the created `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer refers to java swing!**

It is wrong to modify the UI with the new Thread. UI should be modified by the UI thread!
Please use invoke later to update your UI!
https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    if (input_text.getText().length() > 0) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextMessage message = new TextMessage(input_text.getText().toString(), 0, MainHandler.getUserID(), MainHandler.getUsername());
                MainHandler.sendObject(message);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        input_text.setText("");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

And of course you need to start the thread.

Comment: Thank you!, will put the input_text outside the Thread then.

Comment: Note that that link you provided is about Swing. This question is about Android.

Comment: You are right =) Sorry, I didn't see the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `Thread.start()`. Otherwise the Thread object is sitting there waiting to start.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html